# trigger.io error building "No module named generate_dynamic"

Tags: build, trigger.io, forge

I seem to have a strange error when trying to build my app

```
Couldn't import generation code: No module named generate_dynamic
```

What is strange about this error is that I can seem to resolve the error if I uninstall and re-install trigger.io but if I make any changes tot he config the error comes back and I have to uninstall and re-install each time I make a change to the configs. It never used to do this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\async.py", line    106, in run
result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\trigger\api\app.py", line 290, in package
build(cookies, path, target)
File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\trigger\api\app.py", line 329, in build
forge_main.development_build([target, '--general.interactive', 'no'])
File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\main.py", line 335, in development_build
manager.fetch_instructions()
File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\templates.py", line 90, in fetch_instructions
import_generate_dynamic(do_reload=True)
File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\build.py", line 48, in import_generate_dynamic
raise ForgeError("Couldn't import generation code: {0}".format(e))
ForgeError: Couldn't import generation code: No module named generate_dynamic
```

That is the debug. Note sure what is going on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like its not resolved, I tried to update a module and the whole thing blew up again. I sent the logs to support so we will see how long this will take.

*** Edit ***

I was able to resolve this by deleting the trigger.Io directory ( the uninstall does not do this ) then reinstalling and importing my project again. Not sure what happened but it's working now

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did? Having the same issue on a Mac. What was the folder you deleted? Are you referring to your own code or a system folder related to Trigger?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the .tempalte folder and re-built. Looks like the content of that folder got jacked during a failed or canceled build.